# Read/Parse all supported resolution from monitor's EDID hex string C#

Tags: c#, resolution, edid

I have the EDID hex string for specific monitor I want to display all the supported resolutions in drop down using C#. Can anyone suggest which block contains the info related to all supported resolution and how to parse it using C#

I am able to get the basic monitor details and highest supported resolution but could not find out a way to read/parse all resolutions supported by monitor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've the hex edid string which is has all details specific to monitor. I am able to parse and get few basic details like manufacturer id, edid version, serial number. I want to further read and parse the info related to supported resolutions, supported colour resolution etc. I am new to EDID so not sure which block contains this information and what is the proper way to parse it using C#.